# Apache Solr - Wrong facet count

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Are there any known issues in Solr 3.6, where when grouping, filter query (fq) is applied with faceting, the facet counts are coming back wrong.

If I have a query:

```
..indent=on&wt=json&start=0&rows=500&q=*:*&group=true&group.truncate=true&group.ngroups=true&group.field=Id&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field={!ex=filed1}field1&
facet.field={!ex=filed2}field2
```

if user filters on field1, then I have following query:

```
...indent=on&wt=json&start=0&rows=500&q=*:*&fq={!tag=dt}field1:value&group=true&group.truncate=true&group.ngroups=true&group.field=Id&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field={!ex=dt}field1&facet.field={!ex=dt}field2
```

I'm noticing that the facet counts for are different in the results coming back from each query.

thanks,

Comment: post ur result data too..

Comment: in results the number for field1 and field2 are different. in the first result: it is 3, 4. Result for the second query is 2, 0

Comment: can you have a look if there is any empty facet coming back too?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two problems here:

1. You are misspelling **field1** as **filed1** in your !ex queries.
2. You are using **!ex** local parameter but without [corresponding **!tag** parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters).

Comment: Even after making those changes, still seeing wrong facet counts.